# How can I ignore extra arguments with jargo?

Tags: java, command-line, type-safety, jargo

I'm trying to allow [jargo](https://github.com/jontejj/jargo) to ignore any amount of "junk-be-here" strings. How can I do that? This is the code I've come up with:

```
@Test
public void testUsage() throws Exception
{
    Argument<Integer> nrOfPotatoes = Arguments.integerArgument("-n").build();
    ParsedArguments parsedArguments = CommandLineParser.withArguments(nrOfPotatoes).parse("-n", "123", "junk-be-here");
    int potatoesToPlant = parsedArguments.get(nrOfPotatoes);
    System.out.println("Hold on, planting " + potatoesToPlant + " potatoes");
}
```

But I get:

```
se.softhouse.jargo.ArgumentExceptions$UnexpectedArgumentException: Unexpected argument: junk-be-here, previous argument: 123
at se.softhouse.jargo.ArgumentExceptions.forUnexpectedArgument(ArgumentExceptions.java:299)
at se.softhouse.jargo.CommandLineParserInstance.getDefinitionForCurrentArgument(CommandLineParserInstance.java:329)
at se.softhouse.jargo.CommandLineParserInstance.parseArguments(CommandLineParserInstance.java:262)
at se.softhouse.jargo.CommandLineParserInstance.parse(CommandLineParserInstance.java:234)
at se.softhouse.jargo.CommandLineParserInstance.parse(CommandLineParserInstance.java:228)
at se.softhouse.jargo.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:224)
at
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [indexed](http://jontejj.github.io/jargo/javadoc/jargo/se/softhouse/jargo/ArgumentBuilder.html#names-java.lang.String...-) argument (by specifying no names to the argument), and set [variableArity](http://jontejj.github.io/jargo/javadoc/jargo/se/softhouse/jargo/ArgumentBuilder.html#variableArity--) (any amount of arguments is allowed).

```
    @Test
public void testUsage() throws Exception
{
    Argument<List<String>> junk = Arguments.stringArgument().variableArity().build();
    Argument<Integer> nrOfPotatoes = Arguments.integerArgument("-n").build();
    ParsedArguments parsedArguments = CommandLineParser.withArguments(junk, nrOfPotatoes).parse("-n", "123", "junk-be-here");
    int potatoesToPlant = parsedArguments.get(nrOfPotatoes);
    System.out.println("Hold on, planting " + potatoesToPlant + " potatoes");
    System.out.println("Junk:" + parsedArguments.get(junk));
}
```

This prints:

```
Hold on, planting 123 potatoes
Junk:[junk-be-here]
```